# How to pass an argument to PassengerStartupFile?

Tags: passenger, strapi

e.g. in .htaccess:

```
PassengerStartupFile node_modules/strapi/bin/strapi.js develop
```

(it isn't working, because PassengerStartupFile takes only one argument)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it may be too late, you can create an entry point in the root of your project ./server.js and pass this code here:

```
const strapi = require('strapi');

strapi(/* your config */).start();
```

In .htaccess file:

```
PassengerStartupFile server.js
```

Please, read [this](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/getting-started/deployment.html#application-configuration)